# How do i get headers from Browsermob-proxy?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, browsermob-proxy, har

What i need : Proxy server log file of a session that **includes content/text** of the traffic/responses.
What i have : Working silenium webdriver and browsermobproxy server log (*but without headers!).

*browsermob-proxy working on localhost:8080/proxy/8081*

Partial Code:

```
bmp_path = "path-to-browsermob-proxy.bat"
server = Server(path=bmp_path)
server.start()
proxy_server = server.create_proxy()
proxy_server.new_har()
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server={}'.format(proxy_server.proxy))
browser = webdriver.Chrome("path-to-chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser.get('www.demowebsite.com')
```

When printing:

```
pprint(proxy_server.har)
```

{"log":{"version":"1.2","creator":{"name":"BrowserMob Proxy","version":"2.1.4","comment":""},"pages":[{"id":"Page 0","startedDateTime":"2019-10-03T15:17:20.385+03:00","title":"Page 0","pageTimings":{"comment":""},"comment":""}],"entries":[],"comment":""}}

So far so good, Now here is the thing.

When i add any param to *new_har* like:

```
proxy_server.new_har(options={'captureHeaders': True})
```

Or:

```
proxy_server.new_har('test') # for ref param
```

Always get a 500 response from the server:

```
r = requests.put('%s/proxy/%s/har' % (self.host, self.port), payload)
```

> Problem accessing /proxy/8081/har. Reason: Server Error
>
> {JSONDecodeError}Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

It looks like i can't make a request to the proxy server ? 
Thanks for helpers

Answer (score 1):

This probably will not work entirely, I'm facing the same type of issue. 
This is what I did:

```
rput = requests.put('http://localhost:8080/proxy/8082/har',headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"},data={"captureHeaders":True,"captureCookies":True,"captureContent":True})
```

It looks like Browsermob proxy doesn't like the params argument to used. Instead, try to send your request with data.

Note I still am not able to get all the headers and cookies, if you figure it out I'd appreciate it if you let me know :)

Comment: it is a nice idea.
i get 200 OK, BUT STILL NO HEADERS

Comment: For me, it only shows my request headers (which was good enough for what I was doing). It doesn't show response headers. Have you tried to initialize it from PowerShell / CMD?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the DNS cache associated with the proxy instance

```
proxy_server.clear_dns_cache()
```